# Which RSA and AES transformations are best in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, rsa

I want to implement hybrid encryption.
(AES key gets encrypted with RSA)
But I am stuck in deciding the best transformation to use with

```
Cipher.getInstance("?")
// java - android
```

I came to know that OAEPPadding is better than PKCS1Padding, but Android provides multiple OAEP padding schemes like `OAEPwithSHA-1andMGF1Padding`.

Will there be any impact using ECB mode in RSA?

Android documentation of Cipher class:
https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher

Comment: The mode component of the transform string for RSA is ignored, so you can put ECB or CBC or anything. `OAEPwithSHA-1andMGF1Padding` should be secure but it would be nice to get SHA1 out of the crypt ecosystem, so use one of the SHA2-based OEAP algs, like `OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding` **unless** you need interoperability with software that only supports `OAEPwithSHA-1andMGF1Padding`.

Comment: Android also provides OAEP with SHA 224, 384, 512 for RSA. Which one is best?

Comment: It makes little difference securitywise, so the best choice is the one with maximum interoperability/portability, and from your link we see that `OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding` is available from API level 10+, so I think that gives it a slight edge.

Comment: What about AES?

Comment: For AES - anything should be good until you skip the ECB mode. The most commonly used I see is `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding`, but the CBC mode requires random IV and an authentication tag to be safe.  `AES/GCM/NoPadding` will already append the authentication tag itself, but may not be available in earlier versions out of box